# How to access the value of specific cell in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have to move excel table. I have figured out until in excel I am doing something like: `=$c$2/c11`. In Tableau I've done the averages based on filters, so that I am not counting the row 2. Now I have to do that rapport, that is always based on a fixed value (from the filtered row) and I have no idea how to do it. Any help please? I am new to tableau

Comment: I think u should look here for some help: 
http://kb.tableau.com/ 
In the “Visual Analysis” paragraph you'll see “Calculations” and “Actions & Filters” chapters. These chapters may contain useful information for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give a broad answer, for a broad question.

Tableau does not work like Excel. It's closer to Access (or SQL) than to Excel. It does not see an excel table like a collection of cells, with addresses based on row and column. It sees it as a database table, a collection of entries.

So there are three options:

1) If the fixed value is constant, you can create a parameter, and use it in a calculation

2) If it's like, the max value of a column, or the third value ordered by some criteria. Depends on what you are doing and how your table works, it's possible to achieve this using table calculations.

3) Use a RAW_SQL command to get exactly the cell you want

For 2 and 3 I need you to be more specific and clear, about what your table looks like and what you're trying to achieve